# Separate rows based on a column that has min value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table that has attendance of employee. This table has two columns:

- first is the personnel number
- second is the time of arrival

I want to isolate the earliest time in this table, because an employee can register multiple times.

Indeed I want to gain Least time of arrivalTime field for each personelNumber

I wrote the following code but it's wrong and can't separate rows

```
SELECT   tal.PersonNo, min(tal.AttendanceTime)
FROM     mqa.T_AttendanceLog tal
GROUP BY tal.PersonNo, tal.AttendanceTime
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: I didn't understand, are you trying to get only one login transaction of an employee which is the newest one ?

Comment: i want to gain Least time of arrivalTime field for each personelNumber

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. Just remove the `AttendanceTime` from the group by.

```
SELECT tal.PersonNo, min(tal.AttendanceTime) 
  FROM mqa.T_AttendanceLog tal
 GROUP BY tal.PersonNo;
```

If you want the entire row (incase you have other columns) you can use something like this:

```
select *
  from mqa.T_AttendanceLog a
 where (PersonNo, AttendanceTime) in(
         select b.PersonNo, min(b.AttendanceTime)
           from mqa.T_AttendanceLog b
          group by b.PersonNo);
```

Comment: thanks second query help me cuz i need other columns, but this error raise : An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','

Comment: I don't know the error message you got, but I forgot the alias in the subselect. Let me know if it works efter the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your group by clause

```
SELECT tal.PersonNo,min(tal.AttendanceTime)
     FROM mqa.T_AttendanceLog tal
 GROUP BY  tal.PersonNo
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need the minimum of `AttendanceTime` for each day. Try this:

```
SELECT tal.PersonNo,min(CAST(tal.AttendanceTime AS Time))
FROM mqa.T_AttendanceLog tal
GROUP BY  tal.PersonNo,CAST(tal.AttendanceTime AS Date)
```

Comment: thanks for replay but Explicit conversion from data type time to date is not allowed occur .Meanwhile i need other columns except  attendanceTime and personel number in attendancelog table